List of arithmetic sequences and cumulative sums
I have a list of time (seconds) that looks like that:
l = [2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,30,60,30,60]


2,4,6,8 is the first time interval.

2,4,6,8,10 the second time interval.

30,60 the third time interval.

30,60 the forth time interval.


I would like to create a cumulative list of time like below so i can plot the data:
l = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,48,78,108,138]


What is the rule for grouping. In other words, how do you know the groups are not  [(2,4,6,8), (2,4,6,8,10,30), (60), (30,60)] or [(2,4,6,8), (2,4,6,8), (10,30,60), (30,60)] instead?

Code
make l to pandas series s
import pandas as pd
l = [2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,30,60,30,60]
s = pd.Series(l)

s
0      2
1      4
2      6
3      8
4      2
5      4
6      6
7      8
8     10
9     30
10    60
11    30
12    60
dtype: int64

Your logic is too unclear to provide code that solves your problem. However, if each of your interval groups is assumed to be the same interval, and each group has a sufficient number of intervals(like your example), you can try the code below.
grp = s.mul(2).eq(s.shift(-1)).cumsum()
out = s.add(grp.map(s.groupby(grp).max().cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))).tolist()

out
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 48, 78, 108, 138]


can u pls explain me how grp and out is working??

You can use an algorithm to breakdown the l based on arithmetic sequences, generate the expected output using res += [res[-1] + prev_diff] and finally plot the result:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _sequences(L):
    if len(L) < 3:
        return L
    start, parts = 0, []
    prev_diff = L[1] - L[0]
    D = {}
    j = 0
    res = [L[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        curr_diff = L[i] - L[i - 1]
        if prev_diff != curr_diff:
            D[j] = prev_diff
            j += 1
            parts.append(L[start:i])
            start = i
            prev_diff = L[i + 1] - L[i] if i + 1 < len(L) else 0
        res += [res[-1] + prev_diff]
    parts.append(L[start:])
    D[j] = prev_diff
    return parts, D, res


L = [2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 30, 60, 30, 60]

parts, D, res = _sequences(L)

print(parts, D, res)

plt.plot(res, marker='o')
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()




Prints
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [30, 60], [30, 60]] {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 30, 3: 30} [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 48, 78, 108, 138]



They are given a list that looks like l = [2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,30,60,30,60] not parts = [[2, 4, 6, 8], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [30, 60], [30, 60]] It looks like you ignored the main challenge in the question.
